# Parsing Email Addresses/Phone numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that parses email addresses and phone numbers from a website. I have some code but it has errors that I'm not quite sure how to resolve. Could anyone help? I posted a question previously about this but I was so overwhelmed yesterday that I took a step back and tried it again today with better results but I still need a little help please? Thank you.

```
import sys, urllib, re
from email.parser import Parser

def getEmail(page):
    print '[*] getEmail()'
    emails = re.findall(r'\w+@\w+', page)
    emails.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(emails)), 'Emails Found:'

    for mail in emails:
        print mail

def getNumbers(page):
    print '[*] getNumbers()'
    numbers = re.findall('r‘\d+[- ]\d+', page)
    numbers.sort()
    print '[+]', str(len(numbers)), 'Numbers Found:'

    for no in numbers:
        print no

def main():
    sys.argv.append('http://www.edinburghcollege.ac.uk/')
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print '[-] Usage: Webpage Email URL'
        return
    page = getWebpage.getWebpage(sys.argv[1])
    getEmail(page)
    getNumbers(page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output that I get;

```
[*] getEmail()
[+] 2 Emails Found:
info@edinburghcollege
info@edinburghcollege
[*] getNumbers()
[+] 0 Numbers Found:
```

It only finds 2 emails and no telephone numbers. I want it to search all pages on the website not just the first. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Where is `getWebpage` defined? In any case, I don't think the builtin libraries have any simple way to find "all pages on the website". AFAIK, a domain can have an unlimited number of pages, and they aren't obligated to nicely list all of them in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of the regex looks different in the two cases. The regex for the numbers starts with an apostrophy

```
emails = re.findall(r'\w+@\w+', page)
numbers = re.findall('r‘\d+[- ]\d+', page)
```

Check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: `re.findall('r‘\d+[- ]\d+', page)` maybe you shall fix this.

Comment: Also, your regex will only match the first two sections of digits separated by `'-'` or `' '`. I notice a number on that page that has 3 sections. Try this instead: `\d+([- ]\d+)*`

Comment: Hi.Thank you for answering. This regex brings back numbers but it brings me every number on the page. I'm trying to just return telephone numbers. That's what I was originally intending with my first regex. Is there a different way i could try for just telephone numbers, numbers containing only 11 characters and maybe whitespace?


I've managed to do it using this: r'\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\d\s\d\d\d\d' 
Is there another way?

Comment: You don't need to concatenate the placeholder one after another. Imagine you would try to find numbers with 1200 digits. You can put the count in curly brackets after the expression.
If you want an expression that accepts strings with 11 tokens (either a number or a whitespace) try this one:
[\d\s]{11}